# Git untracked files and "working directory"

Tags: git, working-directory

I am new to Git and VCS.I have one question which is killing me for few days.If Git doesn't care about  the untracked file in the git project why did it show the status of git repo under untracked file when you issue a git status command?

Does a working tree has to be necessarily inside a git project that I have cloned? Is working tree a virtual concept?

[image]

Comment: I feel like the other answers didn't address your question about the worktree. Worktree is a confusing term at first but is basically a synonym for your "working directory", or the folder that you're using to edit your code. It's called a tree because the worktree records all of the files, directories and subdirectories from the location of your .git directory down - they're contained in a tree data structure.

Answer (score 5):

Git cares about the untracked files. They are new to a Git repository. Here "untracked" is an important [status](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format) like `modified`, `deleted`, etc. You *may* want to track them, who knows. If you don't want to see them in `git status` but have to keep them, [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) helps. And, Github's recommended [.gitignore files](https://github.com/github/gitignore) for many popular operating systems, environments, and languages.

A working tree is inside a repository in most cases, as it's natural and convenient. But one `.git` can have [multiple working trees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). This way, extra working trees are outside of a repository. Here is a good and brief [article](https://medium.com/statuscode/saving-time-with-multiple-working-trees-in-git-cba4bf5419d3) about `git worktree`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a working tree has to be necessarily inside a git project that I have cloned?

As ElpieKay answered, no, it does not *have* to be, but it is normal.  Every Git repository comes with one—well, every *non-bare* Git repository.  (You don't need to worry about a "bare repository" yet, but it's just one that has no work-tree, so that you cannot use it to do any work.  That might seem odd, and it is odd.  It's how places like GitHub store your repositories, though.)

> Is working tree a virtual concept?

I am not sure what you mean by this phrase.  It is a *version control* concept, especially in modern version control systems.  These generally separate things into *files that are committed / checked-in*, and *files you are currently working on*.  The committed files go into the repository, where they live forever in a frozen snapshot, and the ones you are actively working on, where you can use them and change them.  The working form files go into the work-tree or working tree (there are a few variations on how to spell this, with or without a hyphen; use whichever you like).

With Git in particular, there is one more thing you need to know about, and that is what Git variously calls the *index*, or the *staging area*, or occasionally the *cache*.  These are all one thing—one concept—it just has three *names*.  It's useful to compare Git to Mercurial, another reasonably modern and very similar VCS, here, along with other VCSes: Mercurial and other VCSes *do* have a repository and a work-tree (or working tree), but *do not* have an index.  So Git is unusual.  Here's how to think about this:

- Files that are *committed* are in frozen (read-only) snapshots.  To make them take less space, Git stores them in a special, Git-only format.  This format is compressed, sometimes very compressed, in a way that few other programs can read.
- Files that you are working on go in your work-tree, where you can work on them.  Here they have their ordinary, uncompressed form, and of course you can overwrite them.  You an also store, in your work-tree, files that Git is not going to freeze into snapshots: these are the *untracked* files.
- Git's *index* is a special intermediary, sort of halfway between commit and work-tree.  Files that are in the index are already compressed into the Git-only format, but they're not yet *committed* (frozen).  They are 100% ready to *be* committed, but not actually committed yet.

Running `git commit` simply freezes whatever files are in the index *right now*.  That's why `git commit` is so incredibly fast: if you have used other VCSes, many of them are very slow when you run their "commit" verb, because they spend a lot of time scanning through directories, compressing files, getting them ready to be frozen.  In some VCSes you could practically go get a coffee while waiting for a commit to happen. :-)

If you think of the index as *what Git would commit, if you ran `git commit` right now*, you have a good concept of Git's index.  This naturally leads to the proper definition of a *tracked file* vs an *untracked file:* a *tracked* file is one that is in the index right now, so that it will be in the next commit; an *untracked* file is one that isn't in the index right now, but is in the work-tree.  (If a file isn't in *either* the index *or* the work-tree, it's just not a file at all.)

---

There's something else that's important above: note that we have not yet mentioned the word *branch*.  That's because Git is much more concerned with *commits* than it is with *branches*.  These commits—the frozen snapshots that you have Git make with `git commit`—*make up* your branches, so the branches emerge by having the commits.  That makes the commits the most important part: in Git, the branch *names*, like `master`, are mainly used just to *find* the commits.

Git is very different from a lot of other VCSes here, too.  In other VCSes, the branches are super-important, because the commits exist because they are in branches.  Commits thus *depend on* branches.  In Git, it's the other way around: commits exist first, and only then do we add branch names.  Git lets us *move the names around*, without ever changing the commits at all!

The true name of any commit is its big ugly hash ID.  When you run `git log`, that prints out these hash IDs.  The hash ID of a commit never changes, because that's the real name of the commit.  The *branch name* is just a human-readable name that we stick on some commit, and then as we work, we *move* the human-readable name to the *latest* one.  So if we start with a tiny repository with just three commits, we can draw it like this, using letters instead of hash IDs:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

The *name* `master` remembers the hash ID of the *latest* commit, commit `C` here.  Commit `C` remembers the ID of commit `B`.  Git calls `B` the *parent* of `C`, so that `C` is a child of `B`.  Meanwhile `B` remembers the ID of its parent `A`.  `A` is our very first commit, so it has no parent.  We say that the name `master` *points to* `C`, and `C` points to `B` which points to `A` (and `A` points nowhere).

When we check out `master`, we're really checking out commit `C`.  This puts a copy of all of `C`'s frozen snapshot into both the index (in Git-only form, but now we can overwrite the files) *and* the work-tree (in normal form).  Then we do some work in the work-tree, and when we're done working, we run, e.g.:

```
git add README.txt newfile.py
```

This copies the *work-tree* version of each of these files into the index.  If there was already an index version of `README.txt`, this replaces the index version.  If `newfile.py` is really new, this copies it into the index, so now it's *tracked*—and, except for being compressed into a Git-only form, the `newfile.py` in the index now matches the one in the work-tree.

Then we run:

```
git commit
```

which (after collecting a log message and so on) makes a new snapshot `D` from whatever is in the index: the same old `existing_file.txt` that was in `C`, the updated `README.txt`, and the new file `newfile.py`, perhaps.  The new commit `D` has, as its parent, the commit we had checked out, i.e., `C`: `D` store's `C`'s hash ID, so that `D` points back to `C`.  `D`, being a new commit, gets a new, unique hash ID, too: Git somehow comes up with a big ugly hash ID (we don't have to worry much about *how*, especially since we can't change it :-) ).

As its last trick, `git commit` writes `D`'s hash ID into the name `master`:

```
A  <-B  <-C  <-D   <--master
```

So now `master` points to the latest commit, as always.  Moreover, since Git just made `D` *from* the index, the index and `D` match.  As long as you updated all the index files from all the work-tree files, the index and work-tree *also* match: everything matches, and `git status` says "working tree clean".

Comment: It's an old question, but I suspect OP was just unclear about what worktree meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you create new files, Initially it will not added to any branch. So, it will show as un-tracked files.

If you want to add all those changes  use

```
git add -A
```

or

```
git add path/to/fileName
```

If you want to remove all those changes means,

```
git clean -fd
```